# How to post picture to Twitter using twitter4j library in Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I want to post image to twitter on my app. I use "twitter4j" library to post only text. But i cannot find how to post image with text. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To post a image you have to use media extension of Twitter4j and register your app with either TwitPic or YFrog .
2. Get KEY and TOKEN from those services and then

   ```
   /*
    * Upload File to twitPic and get url . Then append this url to your twitter message.
    */
   public static String upload_twic_pic(File file)
                   throws TwitterException {
           String url = null;
           if (file != null) {
       Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder().setMediaProviderAPIKey(TWITPIC_KEY).build();
       ImageUpload upload = new ImageUploadFactory(conf).getInstance(MediaProvider.PLIXI); //Use ImageUploadFactory
                   url = upload.upload(file);
           }
           return url;
   ```

Comment: It doesn't work. App is crashing because of 
    ImageUpload upload = new ImageUploaderFactory(conf).getInstance(MediaProvider.PLIXI);

Comment: Have u added Media extension jar of Twitter4j ? Also post trace.

Comment: @user408904 ImageUpload upload = new ImageUploadFactory(conf).getInstance(MediaProvider.PLIXI); i get a oauth authorization is required error in this line.Could you help me out.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13931718/994876) is a link to a one file solution that explains exactly how to integrate picture/text tweets into an android app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use socialauth android library

[Find SocialAuth Android Here](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)