# How to post picture on Twitter from android application using Twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, image-upload

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693586/how-to-post-picture-to-twitter-using-twitter4j-library-in-android/9693725#9693725) for the same type of question. when i am using the code its always throwing an `Twitter Exception`.I am calling it like `upload_twic_pic(new File("my_image_path"));`

and getting following `Exception`

```
W/System.err(2195): Connection reset by peerRelevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
W/System.err(2195):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ea09dc6d or
W/System.err(2195):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=050d9b43
W/System.err(2195): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[ea09dc6d-050d9b43 0237e8c8-9ca5c8e4], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.3}
W/System.err(2195):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:204)
```

Comment: try this for updated twitter4j http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093499/how-to-post-image-to-twitter-in-android/20633178#20633178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661118/android-twitter4j-upload-image/12740436#12740436) which is working like charm. just had to copy and past the code provided in answer and was using old jar file i replaced that with the latest one as instructed in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Upload image on Twitter/Facebbok is so easy with [SocialAuth Android library](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Constants
    /**
     * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
     * consumer key and secret
     * */
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "uTMokDQHlUP8rjl6LEmgjg"; // place your cosumer key here
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "xrI8yw6QBKa0ny7N4Nru01JiX4sIThsxzGV4MJ3YOUY"; // place your consumer secret here

    // Preference Constants
    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "hello://sample";

    // Twitter oauth urls
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

    // Login button
    Button btnLoginTwitter;


    // Progress dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Twitter
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;

    // Shared Preferences
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;



    // Alert Dialog Manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());




        // All UI elements
        btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);


        // Shared Preferences
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

        /**
         * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
         * */
        btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Call login twitter function
                loginToTwitter();
            }
        });




        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                // oAuth verifier
                String verifier = uri
                        .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                try {
                    // Get the access token
                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                            requestToken, verifier);

                    // Shared Preferences
                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                    // After getting access token, access token secret
                    // store them in application preferences
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    // Store login status - true
                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                    e.commit(); // save changes

                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());



                    // Getting user details from twitter
                    // For now i am getting his name only
                    long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                    User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                    String username = user.getName();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Check log for login errors
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to login twitter
     * */
    private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            new updateTwitterStatus().execute("helloooo");

        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to update status
     * */
    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            //Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                // Access Token 
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);

                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

                // Update status

                StatusUpdate ad=new StatusUpdate("RaagFm");



                // The InputStream opens the resourceId and sends it to the buffer
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.icon);

                ad.setMedia("RaagFm",is);

                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(ad);



                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
         * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
         * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }
            });
        }

    }




    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm for me.. for Posting image with text.. Hope this will help someone
https://github.com/learnNcode/DemoTwitterImagePost
Thanks