# Android twitter4j upload image

Tags: android, twitter4j, multipartform-data

I have an android app through which I can successfully update the twitter status. I am using it to share links to a webpage which displays an image. I think it will be nice to have a scaled down preview of the image along with the tweet the same way instagram does. How do I upload this image along with my tweet?

Comment: try this for updated twitter4j jar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093499/how-to-post-image-to-twitter-in-android/20633178#20633178

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same requirement sometimes back and finally come with the function may be it will help you too.

```
/**
 * To upload a picture with some piece of text.
 * 
 * 
 * @param file The file which we want to share with our tweet
 * @param message Message to display with picture
 * @param twitter Instance of authorized Twitter class
 * @throws Exception exception if any
 */

public void uploadPic(File file, String message,Twitter twitter) throws Exception  {
    try{
        StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);
        status.setMedia(file);
        twitter.updateStatus(status);}
    catch(TwitterException e){
        Log.d("TAG", "Pic Upload error" + e.getErrorMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**Note:** To use this please make sure you have latest jar file i have used [twitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/2.2.5/twitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar) for this

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly! :)

Comment: after replacing my twitter jar from 2.i.i to 2.2.5 as you suggested i am getting new error : AndroidRuntime(7452): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format. previously i was able to tweet but only for image upload i was trying that.

Comment: Please what is Twitter twitter

Comment: Twitter is an Object used from Twitter4j Library

Comment: How 'bout if I wanted to share a link?

Comment: This doesnt work form me... Please help me.. I want to upload image with status on twitter .. I am able to update status. But when.i use status.setMedia(file); it give me error
 StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message);
          status.setMedia(file);
           //twitter.uploadMedia(file);
          twitter.updateStatus(status);

Comment: if you want get the id of posted tweet. getId(); doesnt work for statusupdate. please avoid this.. when you require id of tweeted tweet.