# android Image Sharing on twitter using SDK

Tags: android, twitter, upload, photo, twitter4j

I am trying to **upload and share** image using **twitter4j** library but unable to share this. can anyone please give me a working demo for image sharing on twitter that upload an image share on twitter.. i have searched a lot on **google and Stackoverflow** but not found suitable answer.
I've tried with twitter4j 2.2.5 and 2.1.6 but no luck :(
I'll be thankfull if anyone help me out.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12740436/450534

Comment: tried tried and tried.. i thought every thing on stackoverflow tried, my badluck no-one working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved.. auto import not working for me when i update library i used these libraries

- twitter4j-core-3.0.2.jar
- twitter4j-media-support-3.0.2.jar

these imports

```
import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import twitter4j.StatusUpdate;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import twitter4j.media.ImageUpload;
import twitter4j.media.ImageUploadFactory;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
```

and here is the code to share image on twitter

```
            String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

            AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(yourConsumerKey).setOAuthConsumerSecret(yourConsumerSeceret).setOAuthAccessToken(yourAccessToken).setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(yourAccessTokenSeceret);

            Configuration conf = cb.build();

            ImageUploadFactory factory = new ImageUploadFactory(conf);
            ImageUpload upload = factory.getInstance();
            String url = upload.upload(yourImage, yourCaptionWithImage); //image is a File Format and Caption is String
```

upload.upload update your twitter status with image

Comment: It is not working for me,I am getting      (Received authentication challenge is null)Exception