# Can image be attached to a direct msg usig twitter 4j?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to attach a image file or bitmap while sending a direct message in android.
Please help on the same.

Comment: Paste some efforts here.

Answer (score 0):

See the link here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/12740436/3884250

```
 /** * To upload a picture with some piece of text. 
 * * * @param file The file which we want to share with our tweet 
 * @param message Message to display with picture 
 * @param twitter Instance of authorized Twitter class 
 * @throws Exception exception if any 


  */ public void uploadPic(File file, String message,Twitter twitter) throws Exception 
  { 
    try{ 
          StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(message); 
          status.setMedia(file); 
          twitter.updateStatus(status);
     } catch(TwitterException e){ 
           Log.d("TAG", "Pic Upload error" + e.getErrorMessage()); throw e; 
     }
  }
```

Comment: This posts an image, it does not send it as direct message. Wrong answer.

Comment: Its more than 6 years old answer. :p

Comment: It's still visited by people like me, and may confuse some