# How to post image to twitter in android

Tags: java, android, facebook, twitter

I want to post an image that is created in my app to twitter. I don't know how to do this and I was wondering if there is an SDK for titter like there is for Facebook?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

First you need to create an app on twitter

here is code to post message on twitter

```
 ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key));
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(LoginActivity.getAccessToken((context)));
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(LoginActivity.getAccessTokenSecret(context));
        Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
        final Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                private double x;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                        boolean success = true;
                        try {
                                x = Math.random();
                                twitter.updateStatus(message +" "+x);
                        } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                success = false;
                        }

                        final boolean finalSuccess = success;

                        callingActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                        postResponse.onFinsihed(finalSuccess);
                                }
                        });

                }
        }).start();
```

check this [tutorial](http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/tutorial-on-uploading-image-on-twitter-using-twitter4j/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement a sharing intent in Android.

This [answer and code example by user "Second" looks applicable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553017/android-share-via-dialog/3553102#3553102)

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");

share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
   Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/myPic.jpg"));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Intent to post the image on Twitter and you can download the full source code from here [download full source code](http://www.tarunpuri.com/android-tutorial/post-image-on-facebook-wall-using-intent/)

```
Bitmap b =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType(“image/jpeg”);
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, “Title”, null);
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, “Select”));
```